# Add a second Windows hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

A friend gave me a 1 TB hard drive from a Windows computer. I want wipe it and install it in my computer. I already have one Ubuntu hard drive and want another hard drive for Windows 10 Thanks

Comment: What brand/model system? Desktop or laptop? Internal drive or external/USB? Often best to disconnect Ubuntu drive to install Windows to avoid issues, but you must install in same boot mode as Ubuntu, or both must be UEFI or both BIOS boot mode. Often disconnecting a drive, may require you to reset UEFI boot entry for Ubuntu either with efibootmgr or reinstalling grub as UEFI often forgets boot entries when drive disconnected. But still better to disconnect drive than have Windows overwrite part ot it.

Comment: I see intent but not an actual question. What is stopping you from doing this?

Comment: I built the desk top computer. mainboard is Gigabyte 64 bit. At the time I was running 2 hard drives Zorin 09 and windows 10 with boot manager. The windows HD died along with the boot manager. Since I started this Thread I have decided to just buy a new SS HD as I don't know if the one I was given can be trusted,  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to install gparted : `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gparted` and then you can format new hdd and create partition you want.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I've got gparted already on my working HD running Zorin 09. So I will give it a go. I guess once I get windows installed on new HD I'll have to reinstall a boot manager as the one I had is gone when the Windows HD died. I'm no pro at this but I do have a lot of patients. LOL!

Comment: you can install grub2 from ubuntu

Comment: I checked and already have grub 2. I'm assuming when my original second hard drive died it quit showing up in Grub boot menu. I will find out if this is the case when my new hard drive arrives today and get it up and going. Thanks for the help.